# setPixmap crashing when trying to show image in label

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, screenshot, qpixmap

I have created a minimal example with pyqt designer, that changes the text of a label when a button is pressed and is supposed to present a screenshot in the window, via the label.

Unfortunately, the example just crashes when it tries to show the screenshot in the label.

```
from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from pyscreenshot import grab

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(503, 382)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 30, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 100, 47, 14))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.take_screenshot())
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def take_screenshot(self):
        self.label.setText("1?")
        screenshot = grab()
        self.label.setText("2")
        qim = ImageQt(screenshot)
        pix = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qim)
        self.label.setText("3")
        self.label.setPixmap(pix)



    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "PushButton"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "TextLabel"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"screenshot" shares the same memory with "qimg", and as screenshot it is a local variable that when eliminated the associated memory is also eliminated so the QPbelmap of the QLabel when trying to access information will generate a *Segmentation fault*. The solution is to make a copy so that they do not share the same memory

```
def take_screenshot(self):
    screenshot = grab()
    qim = ImageQt(screenshot).copy()
    pix = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qim)
    self.label.setPixmap(pix)
    self.label.adjustSize()
```